# Grails 2.5.3 not resolving arguments of messages on controller

Tags: grails

I have a controller used as a REST API, and some actions return error messages that are I18N and have arguments. The problem I'm facing is the arguments are not being resolved and don't know why.

This is an example of what I'm doing:

```
message(code:'query.execute.error.organizationDoesntExists', args:[organizationUid])
```

On the output, is just `query.execute.error.organizationDoesntExists`. The code is defined in the I18N properties files.

Also, Grails errors don't seem to resolve the arguments, example saving a domain instance that has errors on several fields because no data was provided:

```
Property [{0}] of class [{1}] cannot be null
Property [{0}] of class [{1}] cannot be null
Property [{0}] of class [{1}] cannot be null
Property [{0}] of class [{1}] cannot be null
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Can you provide some more code like when are you using the above code and your `message.properties` file

Answer (score 1):

Probably `query.execute.error.organizationDoesntExists` is not in compiled `messages.properties`. Clean and rebuild your project.